# Word for "the condition of being choked up"

Tags: word-request

I'm after the figurative meaning of choked or choked up, as in

> I choked up when I saw her with another guy.

Here's the context I want to use the word in:

> Observing a loved one at a distance when you can't get any closer is, in a way, a form of ....

Is it chokedness, choking or what?

Comment: I've downvoted because the sentence where you want us to fill in the blank is referring to the act of observing itself, not to the state of mind that is the result of observing:  "Observing ...is...a form of ...."  To parallel **I choked up when...** your sentence would have to say "The feeling when you observe .... is a form of ...."

Comment: And I've upvoted for bringing this to my attention. Thank you :)

Comment: You're asking if  *choked up* exists in noun form.  Choked up, and other adjectival stative phrases like it (mixed up, banged up, charged up, etc) do not have noun counterparts. Native speakers will sometimes facetiously generate bogus abstract nouns from such adjectival phrases, such as "chokedupness" or even "chokeduppitude" to refer to the state as state. The idiomatic way to refer to the state nominally is with **being**:   *being choked up is...*

Comment: .. or with an infinitive phrase with **to be**: *to be choked up is ...*

Comment: Was it as if you were having a lump in your throat?

Comment: @Lucian Sava, It's a translation, but yes pretty much like that

Answer (score 1):

*Choked up* is already somewhat figurative, in the sense that one is not literally choking, but is becoming emotional and starting to cry, and breathing may be more difficult.

You could use the word **suffocating** in this context. It has a figurative meaning similar to choking up in addition to its literal meaning. Figuratively it means **to feel or cause to feel trapped and oppressed**.